new github accounts auth app redirecting to the page 404
i am getting page 404 with ne  created GitHub account . i tried to create outh app with 2 old account and that is working but when i tried to create AUTH app with the account that just created or that is new i am getting error 404 page not found
i tried with both new account and account that is some old
the client id and the client secret i am adding is right the problem is not inside that and for the refrence i am using this https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/tree/dev/src/AspNet.Security.OAuth.GitHub
githubOptions.ClientId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(githubExternalAuthSettings?.GithubClientId) ? nameof(githubOptions.ClientId) : githubExternalAuthSettings.GithubClientId;
 githubOptions.ClientSecret = string.IsNullOrEmpty(githubExternalAuthSettings?.GithubClientSecret) ? nameof(githubOptions.ClientSecret) : githubExternalAuthSettings.GithubClientSecret;

 //store access and refresh tokens for the further usage
 githubOptions.SaveTokens = true;

 //set custom events handlers
 githubOptions.Events = new OAuthEvents
 {
     //in case of error, redirect the user to the specified URL
     OnRemoteFailure = context =>
     {
         context.HandleResponse();
         if (context != null && context.Properties != null)
             context.Response.Redirect(context.Properties.GetString(SiteMapDefaults.ERROR_CALLBACK_ACTION_NAME));
         return Task.FromResult(0);
     }
 };


    /// <summary>
    /// Default value for <see cref="RemoteAuthenticationOptions.CallbackPath"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly string CallbackPath = "/signin-github";

    /// <summary>
    /// Default value for <see cref="OAuthOptions.AuthorizationEndpoint"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly string AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize";

    /// <summary>
    /// Default value for <see cref="OAuthOptions.TokenEndpoint"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly string TokenEndpoint = "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token";

    /// <summary>
    /// Default value for <see cref="OAuthOptions.UserInformationEndpoint"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly string UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.github.com/user";

